# How to use ''let" instead of "var"

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code:

```
  if (input.length >= 3) {
     var filtered_school = _.filter(schools, function (school) {
         return _.startsWith(school.label, input);
    });
  }
this.setState({ options: filtered_school })
```

I can't use 'let' as it can't be seen outside the scope so I can't assign `filtered_school` to `options`.

But I hear that there is no reason to use var in ES6.

How can I use let in this situation?

Comment: If `input.length` isn't equal or higher than 3, `filtered_school` will be undefined in `this.setState`.

Comment: Move the variable declaration into the scope where you intend to use it, like *every other language*. JavaScript's weird `var` semantics are an outlier, not the norm, and it has given developers a very funny idea about how variables should be declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put it outside the `if`:

```
let filtered_school;
if (input.length >= 3) {
  filtered_school = // ...
});
```

`let` is block-scoped, meaning if you define it within the `if` block, it won't exist outside of it so you have to extract it out in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

You declare the variable in the scope you want to use it in. i.e. outside of the `if` block.

```
let filtered_school;
if (input.length >= 3) {
  filtered_school = _.filter(schools, function(school) {
    return _.startsWith(school.label, input);
  });
}
this.setState({
  options: filtered_school
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`let` creates block level scope in ES6, you can declare it outside and assign it in your `filter`.

```
let filtered_school;
 if (input.length >= 3) {
    filtered_school = _.filter(schools, function (school) {
         return _.startsWith(school.label, input);
    });
  }
this.setState({ options: filtered_school })
```

Answer (score 1):

`let` is block scoped, so if `let` is somewhere inside `{}`, or in a logical block, it will only be accessible there. To make it accessibly outside of your example place it outside the `if` statement.

```
 let filtered_school;
 if (input.length >= 3) {
     filtered_school = _.filter(schools, function (school) {
         return _.startsWith(school.label, input);
    });
 }
```